# Date Consolidation VBA Code almost working perfectly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code below that i am trying to use in order to identify when my products are truly available.

```
Sub Consolidate_Dates()

Dim cell As Range
Dim Nextrow As Long
Dim Startdate As Date

Nextrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
Startdate = Range("B2").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1).Value Or _
       cell.Offset(0, 2).Value < cell.Offset(1, 1).Value - 1 Then
        Range("A" & Nextrow).Resize(1, 3).Value = cell.Resize(1, 3).Value
        Range("B" & Nextrow).Value = Startdate
        Nextrow = Nextrow + 1
        Startdate = cell.Offset(1, 1).Value
    End If
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  

End Sub
```

Here is an image of my data dump and what I expect the code to deliver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4GKl.jpg

Here is what the code is currently putting out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJblO.jpg

I can't seem to figure out how to sort my dates in order for the code to give me the correct ranges.

Comment: Welcome to S.O Eklone! I've a few comments for you to take into consideration for better assistance from the community
1. What's the criteria for the products to be "truly available"? 
2. Please note that, even if you provide a code, most users won't be likely to answer "here's what I have/here's what I need" questions.
3. Sample data should be clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Sort your data into ascending start date within product
- Keep track of the maximum end date you have encountered while processing the current "block"

---

```
Sub Consolidate_Dates()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Nextrow As Long
    Dim Startdate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date

    Nextrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
    Startdate = Range("B2").Value
    EndDate = Range("C2").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1).Value Or _
           EndDate < cell.Offset(1, 1).Value2 - 1 Then
            Range("A" & Nextrow).Value = cell.Value
            Range("B" & Nextrow).Value = Startdate
            Range("C" & Nextrow).Value = EndDate
            Nextrow = Nextrow + 1
            Startdate = cell.Offset(1, 1).Value2
            EndDate = cell.Offset(1, 2).Value2
        ElseIf EndDate < cell.Offset(1, 2).Value2 Then
            EndDate = cell.Offset(1, 2).Value2
        End If
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Generated output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! I would of never thought to organize my dates in that format. Thanks @YowE3k. Now im going to try and break it :). CHEERS!